# How to update a element in array by index with jq?

Tags: jq

With this example:

```
[111, 222, 333, 444]
```

I want to change the 3rd element (or other from bash variable).

Comment: It is a json array because I need to do with `jq` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `jq` command :

```
jq --argjson index "$index" '.[$index] |= <new value>'
```

`|=` is the update operator, it lets you change the value of what is addressed on its left hand operand without changing the path, so that you can return the whole array rather than just the updated value.

Note that indices are 0-based, so to change the 3rd element you want to set the bash variable `$index` to 2.

Using `--argjson` instead of the usual `--arg` is needed to avoid handling the variable as a string but rather as a number which we can use as an index.

You can (somewhat) [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/E2RDFDWkhv).

Comment: Yes. I am try with 
```
echo "[111, 222, 333]" | jq '.[1] |= 555'
```

And it returns ```[
  111,
  555,
  333
]
```